# Re-use the product id of the deleted item in ItunesConnect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've deleted an In-App-Purchase items by mistake.

I try to create a new one with the same product id, but the error shows:
[image]

I want to use the same product id instead of create a unique new one. how could I re-use this product id in In-App-Puchase? or it means I should never use the same product id again?

thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is simple, yet painful: `After you use a Product ID for one product, it can't be used again, even if the product is deleted.`

This is the documentation that says so: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html

Comment: is there anyway to un-delete the product ?!

Comment: Can I create new app and reuse the same IAP productid?