# How to remove deleted IAP product identifiers?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Recently I added product identifiers to test IAP in my application. Later I deleted that product identifier by mistake. How do I will get that product identifier again?

I checked this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482532/re-use-the-product-id-of-the-deleted-item-in-itunesconnect) saying it's not possible. But I want to know whether it is not possible even while renewing the apple developer subscription also?. Please do confirm.